# Trigger a function when a key is held down after X seconds?

Tags: key-bindings

I have `highlight-symbol` enabled with the delay set to `0`. It's great, but unfortunately when I navigate by holding down `j` or `k` (evil-mode), the feedback is not great.

So I was wondering if it's possible to temporarily disable highlight-symbol as I'm holding down `j` or `k`. I've tried setting the delay to `0.1` or smaller, but it always seems to feel like it's 1 second.

(Now, I know there are better ways in navigating, but that's beside the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way highlight-symbol handles itself, IMO, is not ideal. In order to be able to navigate at full speed and still have highlighting applied quickly after a pause I had to make some changes to the core functions of the package.

First, highlight symbol actually checks for a 0 delay and acts differently, this isn't needed, so you can redefine `highlight-symbol-post-command` to this version which removes the 0 delay check and just always does highlighting via a timer, not directly.

```
(defun highlight-symbol-mode-post-command ()
  "After a command, change the temporary highlighting.
Remove the temporary symbol highlighting and, unless a timeout is specified,
create the new one."
  (if (eq this-command 'highlight-symbol-jump)
      (when highlight-symbol-on-navigation-p
        (highlight-symbol-temp-highlight))
    (highlight-symbol-update-timer highlight-symbol-idle-delay)))
```

Second, we need to change how the timers are started for highlighting. There is no need to have the timer repeat and no need to use an idle timer over a standard timer. You can redefined `highlight-symbol-update-timer` like as this:

```
(defun highlight-symbol-update-timer (value)
  (when highlight-symbol-timer
    (cancel-timer highlight-symbol-timer))
  (setq highlight-symbol-timer
        (run-with-timer value nil 'highlight-symbol-temp-highlight)))
```

Finally, set the delay time very small, I used .1 seconds.

```
(setq highlight-symbol-idle-delay .1)
```

With these changes I am able to move around the buffer quickly with without unnecessary highlighting occurring and slowing things down along the way. Instead highlighting occurs promptly after I stop moving.

Comment: Perfect! This patch should be applied to the default.

Answer (score 0):

The default delay for highlight symbol (at least according to [this source file](https://github.com/nschum/highlight-symbol.el/blob/master/highlight-symbol.el)) is 1.5 seconds.

If you leave it at the default, or set it back to 1.5 yourself, won't you get the desired effect?

Comment: He wants it less than that. He feels like any value he uses leads to a 1 sec delay.